# Where is stirlerr for binopdf.m?

Tags: matlab

In matlabs statistical toolbox is the function binopdf which can be modified with `edit binopdf`. I simply opened the function that way and saved it in my working directory under the name `logbinopdf.m`.

Without any changes to the code of the function, it now always returns the following error.

```
??? Undefined function or method 'stirlerr' for input arguments of
type 'double'.
```

The function `stirlerr` is used in the code but I can not access it or find any informations about it. Do I have to include something special?

My goal is to modify `binpdf.m` such that it returns the log of its true value.

Comment: The function binopdf is working with the same input which fails in logbinopdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times if you get the error message that a function is undefined for input of type double, it means Matlab cannot locate the correct function on the path. Try `which -all stirlerr` to ensure that the function exists. If not, you may just have an issue with your directory structure.

Additionally, `stirlerr` appears as being "Private to Stats". This suggests that if you remove `binopdf` from the Stats toolbox directory, you may have trouble calling `stirlerr` directly. You could try copying it and placing it in your working directory as well.

Comment: Thank you! I copied it as you suggested and now it works perfectly.